# removing duplicates and adding missing fields using bibtool

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibtool

If you don't mind me asking here a couple of questions which I've searched over on google but was unable to find some coherent examples.

My use case contains of creating .bib files for my work and occasionally merge them to a bigger .bib file. The citekeys I use are of the following pattern author_year_unique_consecutive_letter, (in case of multiple publications from same author in the same year) without the underscores.

Example:

```
doe2018
doe2018b
doe2018c
doe2018d
etc...
```

I would like eventually to achieve the following when merging .bib files to the main bigger one.

1) search all entries in the separate .bib files and if there's a missing field such as for instance `journal` then add a user defined text

I tried the following command looking at the manual of bibtool but seems not to produce the desired output.

`bibtool 'add.field={journal="(journal){%N(journal)}{--no-journal--}"}' ./biblio.bib`

2) before merging everything to the bigger .bib file check for duplicate entries, meaning find entries where they have the same key and same title and resolve those by deleting the excessive entries, in the case where there's only duplicate keys but the titles among those entries are different then extract those entries and dump them in an additional file called duplicates.bib for manual inspection, avoiding merging them altogether in the bigger .bib file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `bibtool` does not really have suitable functionality for this (`add.field` first deletes a field if present and then adds, which is of course not appropriate here). However, there is a Perl library called `Text::BibTeX` that can be used to write your own BibTeX manipulation scripts, which is reasonably well-documented and easy to use. Example `addjournal.pl`:

```pl
use Text::BibTeX;

my $bibfile = Text::BibTeX::File->new("$ARGV[0]") or die "error: $ARGV[0] not found\n";
my $newfile = Text::BibTeX::File->new(">$ARGV[1]") or die "error: cannot write $ARGV[1]\n";

while ($entry = Text::BibTeX::Entry->new($bibfile)){
    if($entry->type eq "article"){
        $journal = $entry->get('journal');
        if(!defined($journal)){
            $entry->set('journal','--no-journal--');
        }
    }
    $entry->write($newfile);
}
```

Sample `modifyref.bib` file:

```
@article{hasjournal,
    author = {Mary Jones},
    title = {First Things},
    journal = {Journal of Things}
}

@article{nojournala,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {On Things},
}

@inproceedings{nojournalb,
    author = {Joe Peterson},
    title = {Briefly Explained},
    booktitle = {Conference of Briefness}
}
```

Result after running `perl addjournal.pl modifyref.bib newref.bib` (note that only the `article` entry has been modified and not the `inproceedings` entry):

```
@article{hasjournal,
  author = {Mary Jones},
  title = {First Things},
  journal = {Journal of Things},
}

@article{nojournala,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {On Things},
  journal = {--no-journal--},
}

@inproceedings{nojournalb,
  author = {Joe Peterson},
  title = {Briefly Explained},
  booktitle = {Conference of Briefness},
}
```

The second problem is a bit more involved, but still reasonably straightforward (`bibmerge.pl`):

```pl
use Text::BibTeX;

my $bibfile1 = Text::BibTeX::File->new("$ARGV[0]") or die "error: $ARGV[0] not found\n";
my $bibfile2 = Text::BibTeX::File->new("$ARGV[1]") or die "error: $ARGV[1] not found\n";
my $merged = Text::BibTeX::File->new(">$ARGV[2]") or die "error: cannot write $ARGV[2]\n";
my $duplicatefile = Text::BibTeX::File->new(">duplicates.bib") or die "error: cannot write duplicates.bib\n";

foreach $bibfile ($bibfile1, $bibfile2){
    while ($entry = Text::BibTeX::Entry->new($bibfile)){
        $bibkey = $entry->key;
        $title = $entry->get('title');
        # if a key is found previously
        if(exists($all_keys{$bibkey})){
            # if the title is not equal to the previous occurrence of this key
            # (no else case: if the title is equal then do nothing with the current entry and do not mark the previous entry)
            if($all_keys{$bibkey}{"title"} ne $title){
                # write previous to duplicate file
                $all_keys{$bibkey}{"entry"}->write($duplicatefile);
                # write current to duplicate file
                $entry->write($duplicatefile);
                # mark previous not to print in merged file
                $all_keys{$bibkey}{"duplicate"} = 1;
            }
        }else{
            # new key, store title and entry object for comparison with following entries
            $all_keys{$bibkey}{"title"} = $title;
            $all_keys{$bibkey}{"entry"} = $entry;
        }
    }
}
# print all entries to merged file except entries marked as duplicate
foreach $bibkey (keys %all_keys){
    if(!exists($all_keys{$bibkey}{"duplicate"})){
        $all_keys{$bibkey}{"entry"}->write($merged);
    }
}
```

Sample `modifyref2.bib`:

```
@article{hasjournal,
    author = {Sue Jones},
    title = {First Things},
    journal = {Journal of Duplicate Titles}
}

@article{nojournalb,
    author = {Jane Smith},
    title = {On Other Things},
}

@article{nojournala,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {On Different Things},
}
```

Results after running `perl bibmerge.pl modifyref.bib modifyref2.bib merged.bib`:

`merged.bib`:

```
@article{hasjournal,
  author = {Mary Jones},
  title = {First Things},
  journal = {Journal of Things},
}
```

`duplicates.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{nojournalb,
  author = {Joe Peterson},
  title = {Briefly Explained},
  booktitle = {Conference of Briefness},
}

@article{nojournalb,
  author = {Jane Smith},
  title = {On Other Things},
}

@article{nojournala,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {On Things},
}

@article{nojournala,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {On Different Things},
}
```

Note that there are several improvements to be made, but this may be sufficient as a proof of concept.